# Combine overlay=true with overlay=false script in one script

Tags: overlay

Hi everyone I need help with this question. I would like to combine 2 or more RSI type indicators while keeping its window down and at the same time the bollinger bands on the chart. All in one script. In a nutshell I intend to merge a script with overlay = true in the study with an overlay = false. It's possible?